# Does distributed TensorFlow requires a distributed file system to save checkpoints?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run some sample codes based on [this tf official tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed).
And I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=la_M6bCV91M&index=11&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKGc_NBoIhTn2Qhraji53cv) which is really nice.
As mentioned in the video above, the chief worker is responsible for saving checkpoints, and it's implemented by tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession.
Then I thought that only the chief worker needs a directory to save checkpoints.
When I run the codes with ps0 on machine1, worker0 on machine2, everything seems ok.
But when I run with ps0, worker0 on machine1, ps1 and worker1 on machine2, errors occurs, and the error in worker0's log is like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "distributed_train.py", line 136, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "distributed_train.py", line 97, in main
    hooks=hooks) as mon_sess:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 415, in MonitoredTrainingSession
    stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 826, in __init__
    stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 549, in __init__
    self._sess = _RecoverableSession(self._coordinated_creator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1012, in __init__
    _WrappedSession.__init__(self, self._create_session())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1017, in _create_session
    return self._sess_creator.create_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 712, in create_session
    hook.after_create_session(self.tf_sess, self.coord)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 450, in after_create_session
    self._save(session, global_step)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 481, in _save
    self._get_saver().save(session, self._save_path, global_step=step)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1669, in save
    raise exc
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: ./train_dir/dist_worker_0/model.ckpt-0_temp_cf2b45f059b74507a65cae9b7a9ea5b4; No such file or directory
     [[Node: save/SaveV2_1 = SaveV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:1/device:CPU:0"](save/ShardedFilename_1, save/SaveV2_1/tensor_names, save/SaveV2_1/shape_and_slices, conv1/biases, conv1/biases/Adagrad, conv2/biases, conv2/biases/Adagrad, local3/biases, local3/biases/Adagrad, local4/biases, local4/biases/Adagrad, softmax_linear/biases, softmax_linear/biases/Adagrad)]]

Caused by op u'save/SaveV2_1', defined at:
  File "distributed_train.py", line 136, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "distributed_train.py", line 97, in main
    hooks=hooks) as mon_sess:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 415, in MonitoredTrainingSession
    stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 826, in __init__
    stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 549, in __init__
    self._sess = _RecoverableSession(self._coordinated_creator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1012, in __init__
    _WrappedSession.__init__(self, self._create_session())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1017, in _create_session
    return self._sess_creator.create_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 706, in create_session
    self.tf_sess = self._session_creator.create_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 468, in create_session
    self._scaffold.finalize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 212, in finalize
    self._saver = training_saver._get_saver_or_default()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 856, in _get_saver_or_default
    saver = Saver(sharded=True, allow_empty=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1284, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1296, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1333, in _build
    build_save=build_save, build_restore=build_restore)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 772, in _build_internal
    save_tensor = self._AddShardedSaveOps(filename_tensor, per_device)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 363, in _AddShardedSaveOps
    return self._AddShardedSaveOpsForV2(filename_tensor, per_device)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 337, in _AddShardedSaveOpsForV2
    sharded_saves.append(self._AddSaveOps(sharded_filename, saveables))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/s`enter code here`aver.py", line 278, in _AddSaveOps
   save = self.save_op(filename_tensor, saveables)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 194, in save_op
    tensors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 1687, in save_v2
    shape_and_slices=shape_and_slices, tensors=tensors, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3414, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1740, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): ./train_dir/dist_worker_0/model.ckpt-0_temp_cf2b45f059b74507a65cae9b7a9ea5b4; No such file or directory
     [[Node: save/SaveV2_1 = SaveV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:1/device:CPU:0"](save/ShardedFilename_1, save/SaveV2_1/tensor_names, save/SaveV2_1/shape_and_slices, conv1/biases, conv1/biases/Adagrad, conv2/biases, conv2/biases/Adagrad, local3/biases, local3/biases/Adagrad, local4/biases, local4/biases/Adagrad, softmax_linear/biases, softmax_linear/biases/Adagrad)]]
```

But the directory ./train_dir/dist_worker_0/model.ckpt-0_temp_cf2b45f059b74507a65cae9b7a9ea5b4  really exists (on machine1).

part of the code (actually from the official tutorial):

```
        # The MonitoredTrainingSession takes care of session initialization,
        # restoring from a checkpoint, saving to a checkpoint, and closing when done
        # or an error occurs.
        with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(
                master=server.target,
                config=config,
                is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                checkpoint_dir="./train_dir/dist_{0}_{1}".format(FLAGS.job_name,
                                                             FLAGS.task_index),
                hooks=hooks) as mon_sess:
            while not mon_sess.should_stop():
                # Run a training step asynchronously.
                # See <a href="./../api_docs/python/tf/train/SyncReplicasOptimizer"><code>tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer</code></a> for additional details on how to
                # perform *synchronous* training.
                # mon_sess.run handles AbortedError in case of preempted PS.
                mon_sess.run(train_op)
```

I searched some questions on stackoverflow and issues on github, answers to similar questions suggest to use HDFS.
Doesn't "Chief worker is responsible for saving chechpoints" mean that I only need a local directory on the machine where the chief worker is located? Am I misunderstanding something? Do I really need to use HDFS or such?

Comment: Did you try passing a custom `Saver` created setting `sharded=False` on your worker_0? (Dunno how this woul affect other workers though). As a side note, HDFS is not strictly necessary, a shared network folder  (e.g., on your worker 0) accessible by all the other PSes will suffice

Comment: As per what's the meaning of "Chief worker is responsible for saving checkpoints", I'd guess it means it's the chief that *triggers* the saving, but then each PS saves its shard. This makes it compatible with the case where you have too many parameters to fit in just one machine's memory.

Comment: @GPhilo Thanks. 1. As for using a custom Saver, I guess I also need to disable MonitoredTrainingSession to automatically save checkpoints, otherwise the same error will arise. I will try this. 2. I agree. I used to assume that each ps will send params to chief worker and chief worker save to local checkpoint files. Now it seems that your guess is true, and it is more efficient.